# How to define schema for a Mongodb document with unstructured arrays?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to create a nodejs site to display the contents of data I've scraped and stored in a mongodb collection. I can do the scraping and get the data into the db, but I can't get it back out. I'm guessing that the problem is not defining the schema correctly in my node model.

The data is all arrays of strings.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ca553dc97c32c1f05aba38d"
    },
    "title": [
        "Official Foreign Reserves(March 2019)"
    ],
    "date": [
        "2019.04.03"
    ],
   "summary": [
        "The Consumer Price Index was 104.49(2015=100) in March 2019. The index decreased 0.2 percent from the preceding",
        "month and rose 0.4 percent from the same month of the previous year.",
        "The index excluding food and energy was 105.32 in March 2019. The index decreased 0.1 percent from the preceding",
        "month and rose 0.8 percent from the same month of the previous year.",
        "For more information, refer to the attached file.",
        ""
    ]
}
```

I've tried to define the schema like so:

```
const ScrapeSchema = new Schema({
  title:{
    type: Array, "default" : []
  },
  date:{
    type: Array, "default" : []
  },
  summary:{
    type: Array, "default" : []
  }
});
```

The object I get back is empty. Mongodb connects fine and there are no errors logged.

I'm currently just using find({}) in the request.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly,

```
let ScrapeSchema = new Schema({      
        title: {
            type: [String],
            required: true
          },
          date: {
            type: [String],
            required: true
          },
          summary: {
                type:[String]
            }
    });
```

---

After export model you can find another module with Scarape.model.find , or however you want
btw you could use date type like  `date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }`,

Comment: Thanks this worked, after forcing the collection name, which was causing a problem also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let ScrapeSchema = new Schema({      
    title: { type: [String], default: [] },
    date: { type: [String], default: [] },
    summary: { type:[String], default: [] }
});
```

or `date: { type: [Date] }`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I ultimately found I needed to force the collection name in order to get the data.